# IndexOutofBoundException why?

Tags: java, itext, indexoutofboundsexception

I got small problem i got error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 29, Size: 29 when i launch this one code error is in line `if ((listaSwiat != null && listaSwiat.get(x) != null) || harm.get(y).getDzienTygodnia(x + 1).equals("Nd"))` but dunno why index should be 30 not 29 any1 can help?

```
for (int y = 0; y < harm.size(); y++) {//wiersze
            c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(harm.get(y).nazwa, stdFont));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(c1);
            c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + harm.get(y).getSumaGodzin() + " / " + harm.get(y).normaGodzin, smallFont));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(c1);
            for (int x = 0; x < harm.get(y).dni.size(); x++) {//kolumny
                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(harm.get(y).dni.get(x).godziny, smallFont));
                //dla swiąt ustal kolor tła na czerwono
                //dla niedziel ustala kolor tla na czerwony
                if ((listaSwiat != null && listaSwiat.get(x) != null) || harm.get(y).getDzienTygodnia(x + 1).equals("Nd")) {
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.RED);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looping over all the elements of harm.get(y).dni and inside the loop you
do

```
if ((listaSwiat != null && listaSwiat.get(x) != null) 
|| harm.get(y).getDzienTygodnia(x + 1).equals("Nd"))
```

The last time through the loop x = 28 and the size is 29. But you do

```
harm.get(y).getDzienTygodnia(x + 1)
```

So you get the element at spot 29 which is out of bounds, because like the other answer stated the index starts at 0 not 1. You have to add a check here to see if you are currently at the last index before checking the next index.

Answer (score 3):

In Java (and many other programming languages), indices start at zero, not one.

This means that, if the size is 29, the last valid index is 28, not 29.

Comment: I really now that. I think there is error somewhere in x+1 or x like said twain249 below

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the specific problem. You need to make sure that `x + 1` is not greater than the size of... whatever is accessed inside of `getDzienTygodnia`.

Comment: getDzienTygodnia = days of april so it should be 30 ///in this case

Comment: Use a debugger to see if that's actually the case. Hint: _it's probably not._

Answer (score 0):

Break apart the line that causes the exception so you can see exactly which call to `get` is failing.

```
boolean listaSwiatCheck = listaSwiat != null && listaSwiat.get(x) != null;
if (listaSwiatCheck || harm.get(y).getDzienTygodnia(x + 1).equals("Nd")) {
    c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.RED);
}
```